# Garage Door already has struts, but is sagging

Tags: garage-door, truss, sagging

16 foot wooden garage door, no telling what the door age is. The bottom, middle and top panels already have 2 1/4" (?) struts installed, presumably to correct previous sagging.

The bottom panel is sagging horribly even though has a strut installed across the bottom edge. What would you recommend to fix the sag:

1. Replace the strut along the bottom?
2. Add another strut along the top edge of the bottom panel?
3. Do both (1) & (2)?

I was hoping to do this myself, although I have no way of transporting a 16 ft long strut and will likely be at the mercy of a garage door repair company anyway.

Comment: Please edit you question and use the 'sun & mountains' button to add a pic or 2. It's hard to visualize what you're trying to describe (since a '[truss](https://www.google.com/search?q=truss)' is usually a part of a roof structure).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I meant "strut" instead of "truss". Struts that are +2" U-channel seem to be the common way to correct sag in garage doors. They "sister" across the affected garage door panel horizontally.

Comment: So the garage door panels bow inward when the door is in the closed position, and the garage door panels sag downward when the door is in the open position?

Comment: Yes, at least the bottom panel sags downward when the door is in the open position. And it is so bowed in, that the strut breaks the sensor beam when it is closing. I moved the sensor beam further inward to the garage to avoid this.